# Changing desktop background in system settings does not update the background

Tags: desktop

As stated in the subject line I selected a different background picture but nothing updates even after closing system settings?

Answer (score 1):

Check what is really written to `org.gnome.desktop.background`.  I see the effect of changing wallpaper immediately.  But if I change the background to solid colour, it gets always black:

[image: grey background chosen]

I found, that it writes the colour in `rgb(...)` format to gnome settings:

[image: wrong colour format]

If I fix the value format in dconf-editor to `#...`, I see the right background colour.  Setting `primary-color` to `#d0d0d0` helped in my case.

If you cannot select a picture, you can have a look if the actually written path is correct.